# dataset split 70-30 SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset that I want to split into 2 groups and the splits to be 70/30. I would also like the split to be random but all items under 1 ID must all be in the same group of the split whether it be on the 70 or 30 side. Was wondering what is the best method to do this using SQL (redshift). I tried using NTILE but that doesn't work so open to ideas.
What i tried was

```
with a as (select *,ntile(10) over (order by ID) tile
from table)
select *, case when tile <= 7 then 1 else 0 as bucket
from a
```

Thanks.

Example data:

| User | ID | column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123214123 | abc | Y |
| 544354342 | abc | N |
| 43241231 | def | Y |
| 231213123 | def | Y |
| 123123123 | abc | Y |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your constraints, you cannot use `ntile()` because it focuses on getting the buckets to be the right size.  Instead, you can use `rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum < cnt * 0.7 then 1 else 0 end) as bucket
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (order by md5(id), id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note that this arbitrarily uses `md5()` to assign a random value to each `id`.  This is repeatable.  An easy way to get different buckets would be to "salt" the value with another string.